# d3.geo.mercator displays shifted right in Chrome

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The map displays in the correct position in Firefox and Safari but in Chrome the g element is shifted right (by about 100 px) inside the svg element.
After some help in Google forum I may have narrowed the problem as follows:

```
var x = $("svg").position();
```

In Firefox the position after applying projections is different whereas in Chrome the projection does not change the position.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I got the map to display in the correct position on Chrome by upgrading D3 to version 5. Took some time to revise the code but after that things worked.